# Inserting transparent new row with UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle animation creates black shadow glitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-animation

I am trying to achieve animation like Inbox iOS app where clicking on one row would expand to full screen, revealing the content inside it. I achieve this by having 1 `UICollectionView` and 1 `UITableView` on top of it. When clicking on `UITableView` row, I insert a blank row below it and also scroll to top to reveal the `UICollectionView` content behind it.

This works perfectly just like Inbox app but here when inserting the transparent row with `UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle` animation so that the transition seems like new row is being pushed in the middle. This causes black shadow glitch for a second when the animation is going on. When I try to change the animation type to any other than `UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle`, the black shadow does not appear. What could be reason for this issue with `UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle` animation?

I created another demo project where this is reproducible. Please check this out: https://www.dropbox.com/s/iz9kuofmlnosgp5/UITableViewAnimationIssue.zip?dl=0

See the issue in the attached image where black shadow is being shown in the area of transparent row when its being inserted.

**Issue with black shadow shown during animation:**

[image: Black shadow issue]

Comment: try CALayers to add different elements, maybe from a view to cell

Comment: Where in the image is the black shadow issue showing?

Comment: I updated the image to highlight the shadow.

Comment: why 0.3 in source code ?

Comment: i have check your source code with different animations, and it seems middle animation have in build animation you are talking about.  Still want to see your code of CellForRow. How are you adding arrow image /\.

Comment: Alok - In the Screenshot that I have attached, the arrow images are added through photoshop to show where the black shadows are visible with the Middle animation.

Comment: Is there a way to override the default behavior of the middle animation in order to not show the black shadow during animation?